# ImportError: No module named custom storages - django-storages boto

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to follow this tutorial for using s3 but pretty much until the last step, somehow I get this error and I am not sure where I should import my own customed module

Tutorial link
https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/

Everything is fine, that I am able to upload / copy / use the static files using s3 then the step about creating custom storage for media usage

```
# custom_storages.py
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

I created that `.py` file inside the same directory as the setting.py (setting.py where it included `INSTALLED_APPS` and more)

then inside the setting I added below as mentioned on the tutorial

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

then I ran `python manage.py collectstatic`

I get this error

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named custom_storages
```

Can someone give me a hand?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess this link might help you: https://disqus.com/home/discussion/wwwcaktusblog/using_amazon_s3_to_store_your_django_sites_static_and_media_files/

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo thx this does help a lot~!~ and found my answer too

Comment: Alright. Also, you can post your answer on your own question as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This credit should go to Shubham Namdeo who gave me the link of https://disqus.com/home/discussion/wwwcaktusblog/using_amazon_s3_to_store_your_django_sites_static_and_media_files/

well there are lots of suggestions and ways / errors people found which helps but as for me the part that helped me solve this problem is just move the `custom_storage.py` into the same directory as the `manage.py` so `manage.py` and `custom_storage.py` are actually in the same level of the directory structure then it all works just like that~

Don't even need to import anything.

I have attached an image of the part where I got my answer so you don't have to scroll all the way down if you have the same problem as mine.

[image: s3]

Answer (score 2):

in my project i have the custom_storages inside a folder and that works maybe moving it might help?

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myapp.custom_storages.StaticStorage'
```

the folder structure looks like this

```
/myproject
   someapp1/
   someapp2/
   myapp/
      settings/
         __init__.py
         production.py
      custom_storages.py
   manage.py
```

Comment: I was using the link @Shubham Namdeo provided and helped, I believe yours should help too it's because I shouldn't place the `custom_storage.py` at where it was if so, I believe I should use how you directed your `STATICFILES_STORAGE` let me give this a try too :D

Comment: I just tried your way, it did get ride of the `module` error but raise another error instead something about package but with the link @Shubham provided by moving the `custom_storage.py` somewhere else actually solves it without any other errors raising up